# How to update selected user state in Angular using ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am new to ngrx in Angular. I am showing a list of users and given a view button based on view click I want to display user info of only selected latest one.

I am using ngrx for this but what happens it merge the new selected with existing one but I want latest one below is my Stackbiltz link. How can I modify it?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxni6k

I know problem is in below line in reducer:

```
export const userReducer = createReducer(
  intialState,
  on(
      fromUserActions.userLoaded,
      (state,{user}) => adapter.addOne(user,{...state,loaded:true})     
      )
);
```

I need to use something else instead of addOne but I am not finding exact one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the reducer, but how the state is structured.

`@ngrx/entity` keeps a collection of loaded entities, it isn't fitted for a single entity imho.

You have two options:

- only store one used in the state, instead of a collection
- keep track of the selected user, this can be done by setting a `selectedUserId` in the store state and by creating a selector which will select the selected user based on the `selectedUserId` and the `users` in the state. See the [example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/books.reducer.ts#L22) for an example.